# What is the significance of last_seq and update_seq in PouchDB replicate?

Tags: pouchdb

When I run *db.replicate.to* I get the following from the **uptodate** event:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "start_time": "2014-06-02T15:48:07.414Z",
    "docs_read": 0,
    "docs_written": 0,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "last_seq": 159,
}
```

And I get the following from **db.info**:

```
{
    "db_name": "LocalDB",
    "doc_count": 147,
    "update_seq": 167
}
```

What is the significance of *last_seq* from the *uptodate* event and *update_seq* from *db.info*?

Why is an uptodoate sync have a value 10 less than the db info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

daleharvey answered on IRC:

> the last_seq is the last seq read from the remote database
>
> update_seq is your local one, its expected they wont be the same